# Allow HTML characters in Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am returning HTML text from Django Rest Framework, but special characters are rewritten as "HTML safe" text.

How do I prevent this behaviour? I know there is a `mark_safe()` function in Django, but that would require me to rewrite the serializer. Is there an easy way to do this offered by DRF?

Here is my serializer:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("html_text",)
```

Note that the text is safe and only input by admins, not by end users.

Comment: Maybe your frontend is doing it?  Can you check what is actually stored in your database, and can you give an example of the actual api output json.  To my knowledge DRF does not do any escaping like this.

Comment: The fronted is not doing it @AndrewBacker. There is HTML in the database and DRF spits out escaped characters.

Comment: This is not a feature of DRF that I have ever heard of, and none of my apis and numerous endpoints do this.  You are going to have to provide a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are right! a JSON beautifier extension was doing this. It works as expected when running cURL. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF does not do this out of the box.

Either your frontend or some other code is doing this for you. This escaping is automatic for all the modern UI frameworks that I know of. I'm not a frontend dev so maybe I missed one.

To demonstrate this I took just a few minutes created an empty project with one model and used the default routers, sqlite, etc.  This is fairly straighforward to do.

```
Package               Version
--------------------- -------
Django                3.2.4
djangorestframework   3.12.4
```

```
~/htm ❯ http post :8000/page/ \
        html_string="<script>window.alert()</script>" \
        html_text="<script>console.log('hi')</script>"
{
    "html_string": "<script>window.alert()</script>",
    "html_text": "<script>console.log('hi')</script>",
    "id": 1
}

~/htm ❯ http :8000/page/1/
{
    "html_string": "<script>window.alert()</script>",
    "html_text": "<script>console.log('hi')</script>",
    "id": 1
}
```

And the views, routers, and models

```
class Page(models.Model):
    html_string = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    html_text = models.TextField()

class PageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = "__all__"

class PageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
```